# Tail recursion for spatial grid algorithms

Tags: geospatial, tail-recursion

I have an algorithm, that operates recursively on a spatial grid:

```
def function(a):
    for i in (neighbours of a):
        if condition=true:
            function(i)
```

So the function is called recursively to partition a grid into subgrids depending on a condition (gradient smaller than a threshold). But since there are always the remaining neighbours in the loop of the function, it is not tail recursive.
Is there a way to rewrite this function to make it tail recursive? I have already looked into accumulators, but I don't see how this could be applied here, because there is no quantity to be summed or anything, but the algorithm expands in multiple directions...